# How to wait for selection input

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JFrame with a JTree on it (created within the function "get_Classification()"). This function should return the name of the selected Node (clicked double) as String.

As soon as i run the application the method returns null, if I then double click on a node the value is printed to console as expected.

I assume the method is finished before the user can select an value (actually 3-4 levels, taking about 5 seconds). If I had a "Thread.sleep(1000)" the JTree is not showing until the second passed...

How can I wait for the user input before the method returns the value and also see the tree beforehand?

Some functions below:

```
public String ret = null;
private DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(top);
private JTree baum = null;

MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        TreePath selPath = baum.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (selPath != null) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selPath.getLastPathComponent();
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && model.isLeaf(node)) {
                ret = node.toString();
                System.out.println(ret);
            }
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Frame window = new Frame();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Frame() {
    initialize();
}


private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    Map<String, String> tree = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tree.put("Klebebänder", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");
    tree.put("Lacke", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");
    tree.put("Pulver", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");

    String k = get_Klassifizierung(tree);
    System.out.println(k);

}

private String get_Klassifizierung(Map<String, String> tree) {
    setupTree(tree); // creates the tree
    waitForInput();

    return ret;

}

private void waitForInput() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Read about [trees in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: The tree and Selection is working, problem is the function finished earlier then the user can react..

Comment: You need to do some research into the "observer pattern", in particular `TreeSelectionListener`. I suggest that you take a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), this concept is fundemental to Swing (and most GUIs)

Comment: `private void waitForInput() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000); ..` No, no and just NO! Don't block the EDT. Add a listener to the tree and query it on event as suggested by @MadProgrammer. But as a general rule, I can say with 99.99% confidence that if Swing GUI code has `Thread.sleep(..` in it, that will cause problems & likely be the *source* of the problem.

Comment: You're missing a fundamental concept common to GUIs, they are event driven, not linear.  You register an observer with the components you're interested in and when something happens, they let you know

Comment: Read: [The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I already read this article and it helped me much creating the Tree and get the selected node,etc... Can you give me some basic code for such an pattern? 

The problem is also that this whole Frame, Tree, Selection should work by only calling "String k = get_Klassifizierung(tree);"

Comment: @IVIike please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so we can understand what you want to do.

Comment: @IVIike That's not how GUI's work.  Instead, you might want to investigate modal dialogs, they will get you closer to how you seem to want to make it work. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the development leader in my company and he had the coding within 2 minutes...

Here is the solution:

File "Main.java":

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Map<String, String> tree = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tree.put("Klebebänder", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");
    tree.put("Lacke", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");
    tree.put("Pulver", "Hilfsstoffe und Beschichtungsstoffe");

    String k = get_Klassifizierung(tree);

    System.out.println(k);

    }

public static String get_Klassifizierung(Map<String, String> tree) throws InterruptedException {
    MyFrame m = new MyFrame(tree);
    while (m.myReturnValue == null) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    m.dispose();
    return m.myReturnValue;
    }

}
```

File "MyFrame.java":

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String myReturnValue = null;

private static String firstn = "Kategorien";
private static String del = "\\|";
private DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(firstn);
private DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(top);
private JTree baum = null;
public String ret = null;

public MyFrame(Map<String, String> tree) {

    this.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setupTree(tree);

    baum.addMouseListener(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

private void setupTree(Map<String, String> tree) {
    baum = new JTree(createNodes(tree));
    baum.setEditable(false);
    baum.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    baum.setToggleClickCount(2);
    baum.setRootVisible(true);
    JScrollPane treeView = new JScrollPane(baum);
    this.getContentPane().add(treeView);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
private DefaultMutableTreeNode createNodes(Map<String, String> file) {
    /*
     * Iterate over the Map
     */
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : file.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String values[] = entry.getValue().split(del);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = top;

        /*
         * Iterate over the values (Path)
         */
        for (String k : values) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode n = null;

            /*
             * Check if Node already exists
             */
            Enumeration<?> e = parent.children();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                n = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
                if (k.equals(n.getUserObject())) {
                    // Existing node matches; use that one.
                    break;
                }
                n = null;
            }
            if (n == null) {
                // No existing node matches; add it.
                n = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(k);
                parent.add(n);
            }
            parent = n;
        }
        parent.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(key));
    }
    return top;
}
// ... other @Overrides
@Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    TreePath selPath = baum.getPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (selPath != null) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selPath.getLastPathComponent();
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && model.isLeaf(node)) {
            this.myReturnValue = node.toString();
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is something like:
Bring up UI -> call a method -> When method returns do something

In GUI applications the workflow needs to be different:
Bring up UI -> attach listener to get callback when user does something
-> do something when you get call back

If you still need to follow previous way, you will need to add some kind of flag, the flag will be set when UI has recieved call back, your wait for input will sleep for small time and check if the flag is set in loop. However, this approach is bad because you will be accessing UI from another thread.

Comment: I've tried it with an Boolean to get true if the node is double clicked, but on the one hand the GUI did not show (because at start the boolean is not true) and on the other the program starts but shows no tree...